# CSS brake line but not word

Tags: css, whitespace, word-wrap

I have an issue that i cant fix with line brakes. The text inside span element 
brakes line in middle of the word. Check first image.

[image]

What i want to do is the line to brake when a word ends. 
check example:

[image]

Any Idea ?

current html:

```
<div class="hgroup">
   <h1 class="fancy-title">
     <span>Leisure &amp; Entertainment</span>
   </h1>
</div>
```

current css:

```
.hgroup{width:200px !important; float: left !important; margin-left:0px !important; display: inline-block !important; } .hgroup .fancy-title { margin-left: 0px !important; display} .hgroup .fancy-title span{-webkit-text-fill-color:#444 !important;}
```

Comment: have you found any solution ? coz I'm looking the same

Answer (score 1):

Setting `white-space` to `break-all` will get an result like in the demo that doesn't break the word.

```css
   .test { 
    white-space:break-all;
    
    width:130px; 
    background:yellow
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Leisure & Entertainment</div>
```

Comment: Still not working on my side. Just to let you know that the text is inside span element. i add white-space:break-all; to span element and nothing happens!